# bootstrap vertical scroll bar disappear when opening developer tools

Tags: bootstrap-4

when i am opening my webpage . it is showing vertical scroll bar. but when i am   doing resize my window or opening chrome developer tools. it disappear.i am using overflow-y:auto . For testing reason, i change its value to scroll. but problem was still consistent. i revert it back again. please see the images below:
 when opening this first time:

[image: with scrollbar]

when opened developer tools :

[image: Scrollbar missing]

Here is also a [JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3z9msar/3/)

```css
.product-content1 {
    background: url("img/circles-light.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 40px 15px;
}
 #videoThumbnails {
 float:left;
 height: 515px;
    width:120px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
#videoThumbnails .thumb {
  //padding:0px;
  padding:11px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
#videoThumbnails img {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  cursor: pointer;
        width:90px; 
        height:60px;
 }
#videoThumbnails .frame {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
.video {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="product-content1 mb-3">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div id="videoThumbnails" class=" col-md-2">
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="1"><img src="img/an_image.jpg" /></div>                    
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="2"><img src="img/header2.jpg" /></div>                                         
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="3"><img src="img/header3.jpg" /></div>                   
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="4"><img src="img/header4.jpg" /></div>    
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="5"><img src="img/header5.jpg" data-video="" /></div>    
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="6"><img src="img/header6.jpg" /></div>    
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="3"><img src="img/header3.jpg" /></div>                   
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="4"><img src="img/header4.jpg" /></div>    
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="5"><img src="img/header5.jpg" data-video="" /></div>    
   </div>
   <div class="thumb">
    <div class="frame" data-thumbnail="6"><img src="img/header6.jpg" /></div>    
   </div>         
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">        
   
   <img id="largeImage" src="img/an_image.jpg" width="100%" height="515"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: for me it does not disapper in your example if i resize my window or use developer tools (Chrome).

Comment: @MrMaavin, but it is happening with me :-(... could you please suggest any better solution ?

Comment: Try to build an example where the problem can be reproduced. Maybe a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: it does not disappear for me also, u can use fiddle or pen for show your proble

Comment: i create fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x3z9msar/ . it's not disappearing here as well... :-(... only in my system ... what to do ?

Comment: @MrMaavin Could you please test the modified fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/x3z9msar/1/ ? Could you please let me know scroll bar is showing or not , while testing using Developer tools ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Nisharg Shah...Could you please test the modified fiddle -jsfiddle.net/x3z9msar/1 ? Could you please let me know scroll bar is showing or not , while testing using Developer tools ? thanks in advance

Comment: same as before, i fully resize all things but scroll bar not disappear

Comment: @Nisharg, please save this code , http://jsfiddle.net/x3z9msar/3/ and than test it in several browser and during resize and responsive mode as well. If it still running fine than i'll leave the code as it is. thanks in advance

Comment: i checked in all browsers like edge chrome firefox, all is fine, no disappear occur

Comment: if you have any problem, share your whole code in form of fiddle and pen

Comment: it's the complete section . just i didn't add my script here. it is not doing anything with styling . i am using that script to change the image only.